# Download Cisco Lightweight AP Image

Tags: cisco, access-point

I currently have a Cisco WLC 2112 and several 1242 lightweight AP's.

Is there any way I can download the IOS image either from the AP's themselves or through the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can download the ios via TFTP. Connect via telnet to the AP and use the download tftp commands, you will have to use a tftp server in your PC. TFTP32 is a very good one.